# Posting "shortcuts" to make my posts look more professional?

Tags: support, formatting

I'm new here, but I am already addicted to reading and answering questions.  I am predominantly on my phone.

How can I beef up my posts?

I recently learned about using `>` at the start of a line to create the yellow-box blockquote effect. Are there any other simple tips and tricks to help make my posts look that much more professional?

Comment: Also, while [it's totally not required](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6367/is-there-a-style-guide-for-posts), if you're interested in the official D&D 5e style conventions, you might find this Q&A useful: [What is the proper way to style references to D&D game elements?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/133453/what-is-the-proper-way-to-style-references-to-dd-game-elements)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It sounds like you should look at the help pages about using [markdown syntax](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/editing-help) and [general formatting guidance](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) - these pages will explain and provide examples of the formatting syntax used on stack exchange.

You can also look at [this excellent answer by SSD](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6368/28402), which, although not an official style guide (as we don't enforce any specific styling), is nevertheless a good set of conventions to keep in mind when formatting questions and answers.

Comment: Yes!!! Exactly what i was looking for!!!

Answer (score 11):

In addition to the [help pages linked by Carcer](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9745/52137), if you find any piece of formatting you like the look of (and want to understand how has been done) you can click the `edit` button beneath the post to view the specific markdown (be sure not to submit an edit if you only mean to look at its source code).

We also have a few posts on meta regarding formatting:

- [Is there a style guide for posts?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6367/52137)
- [Don't signal your edits in text](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3454/52137)
- [Use real headers instead of fake headers](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6498/52137)
- [Is there a functional purpose to putting things in code text here?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1483/52137)
- And the rest of the questions tagged with [formatting](/questions/tagged/formatting) on meta.
- (And if you do get into equations etc., you may have use of math.se's [tutorial on MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020))

As a final note, you can always jump into [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat) if have a quick question about how do a piece of formatting, about the site, or just to, well.. chat.